# Laravel - Correct Work Organization

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, repository

Recently I have finished to read an OOP book, And I have decided to create a project with Laravel Framework.

In the book the author recommended to divide the classes according to their types: DTOs, BLs and Repositories.
Laravel made me a little confused how to organize my system.

I have been thinking to do something like this:

Files Structure:

```
app
  BL
     RegisterUser.php
  Repositories
     UserRepository.php
```

Then to do for example:

// UserController

```
public function register($name, $email)
{
    try {
        $this->registerUser->fromWeb($name, $email);
    }

    catch(..) {

    }

     return View::make(....);
}
```

// RegisterUser

```
public function fromWeb($name, $email) {
    if(...)
        throw new Exception();

    $this->userRepository->createUser($name, $email);
```

}

// userRepository

```
public function createUser($name, $email) {
    // Insert to DB
}
```

I don't ask specific for this action, I ask in general if it's correct to work that way.

In addition, Do I have to use DTO in the model? If so, how it should fit in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say there is any correct way but at first glance to me, it feels like one too many layers.

I believe the models would be your DTO's.  They would include the basic accessors/mutators if you need them, otherwise Eloquent does a pretty good job at taking care of the rest.  A lot of people also use the models for validation as well though this is up to you.  There is an amazing package called Ardent which will make your life much easier if that sounds like a good idea.  For the general Laravel workflow, I think this makes a lot of sense.

Everyone is different, but I usually find myself tending towards a more general service layer where my repositories are responsible for handling all the business logic.  In a nutshell, I use them to keep my controllers as light as possible.  How this translates to what you've read, it's basically combining the business logic and repositories into just repositories.

Then the controllers would strictly be responsible for managing the flow of data between the service layer (repositories) and the views.